# when there are two buttons how to show error message if user tries to click button2 before clicking button1- Javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a user profile information update using php. To update his image, what I do is that first let him delete the image and ask him to upload a new image. If accidentally user click image update button without clicking image delete button how to show an error message as "please first delete your Image and then upload a new image". 
I couldn't find any way of doing it.
A help would be really appreciated
 **Given below is my code**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <center><label>Update A New Profile Picture </label></br></center>
        <form method="post" action="update_userinfo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <center><img id="uploadPreview4" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" /></center>
                <center><input type="file" name="Filename4" id="uploadImage4" onchange="PreviewImage4();" class="form-group"><input TYPE="submit" name="updateImage" value="Update Image" class="btn btn-success" /></center>

        </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <center><label>Your Current Profile Picture </label></br>
        <form method="post" action="update_userinfo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="if(!confirm('Do You really want to update your profile picture?')){return false;}">
            <?php
            echo "<img border=\"0\" src=\"".$row['image_path4']."\" width=\"100\"  height=\"100\" >";
            echo "<br>";  ?>
        <input TYPE="submit" name="delete" value="delete" class="btn btn-success" />
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to disable the update button and make it enabled when the image is deleted?

Comment: @MohammedAhmed No I did not tried it. It means first I should disable the update button, and then on button click I should check whether image is available on database. Am I right?

Comment: it's better that you use something like `Ajax` to upload your photo then once you get response from server that the photo is uploaded in the callback you can enable the button.

Comment: If you're using PHP purely, then you have to load this page again with extra variables from your PHP code and try to enable the button which you will end up shooting yourself trying to do that

Comment: @Bardia I am using pure PHP. That is why I was in this trouble.

Comment: @sadee Yes that's right. The default state of the upload button is disabled and check if the image available or not and if it's not available change the state to be enabled.

Comment: Well This is more of User Experience issue. You have two buttons available, however Delete could happen only when there is an existing Photo and Upload could happen when there is no Photo. So to clear the confusion, I suggest to make your scenario like Till the time Photo is available in database show Delete button, once photo is deleted from Database, show Update Button. I feel at a time there should be one button as per the situation. Please confirm if it makes sense?

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari nice idea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i can think of if you really want to deal with this using PHP ,

considering this is your current code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <center><label>Update A New Profile Picture </label></br></center>
        <form method="post" action="update_userinfo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <center><img id="uploadPreview4" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" /></center>
                <center><input type="file" name="Filename4" id="uploadImage4" onchange="PreviewImage4();" class="form-group"><input TYPE="submit" name="updateImage" value="Update Image" class="btn btn-success" /></center>

        </form>
        ////
          new code
          <?php if(isset($photoDeleted) && $photoDelete=== false) :>
            <center>Hey! Delete your photo first!</center>
          <?php endif; ?>
        ////
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <center><label>Your Current Profile Picture </label></br>
        <form method="post" action="update_userinfo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="if(!confirm('Do You really want to update your profile picture?')){return false;}">
            <?php
            echo "<img border=\"0\" src=\"".$row['image_path4']."\" width=\"100\"  height=\"100\" >";
            echo "<br>";  ?>
        <input TYPE="submit" name="delete" value="delete" class="btn btn-success" />
        </form>
</div>
```

from your PHP side, check, if there is still a photo in db reload this upload page and pass `photoDelete` variable as `false` when it's loading the page php will render this as an error.

But! Wait! 
Why don't you just replace/delete the previous photo with the newly updated one in your php? 
assuming that there's only one record of profile photo for each user, just update your db record with the newly updated photo and delete the previous record !?

it's a better User Experience overall

Comment: thank you very much.First I was trying to replace deleted photo with updated photo selection input.Since I am kind of new one for php I could not figure   out how to do that